# PHP -> MySQL transaction very slow

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem after moving PHP MySQL program from dedicated hosted server to home server.

The problem is the time php need for showing a page with 800 rows (html formated)
I have a table with 816 rows (64 fields) 320Kb. The problem I'll explain is the same on all table. I added an index but no changes. I made MySQL table analyse. Every table is listed as OK and nothing changes.
Running `SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 1000` directly in MySQL:
Dedicated distant server      : 0.02 second
Home server via DynHost       : 0.01 second
Home server via local network : 0.01 second
Running `SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 1000` in PhpMyAdmin:
Dedicated distant server      : 27 seconds
Home server via DynHost       : 40 seconds
Home server via local network : 25 seconds
Running `SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 1000` in program:
Dedicated distant server      :   4 seconds
Home server via DynHost       : 113 seconds
Home server via local network : 113 seconds
The code (PHP) is exactly the some on both servers.
In the program the speed is the same over DynHost or via local network.

As asked by Juanga, server API was running as Apache handler. Actually the server is running:

Ubunutu 16.04.3
Apache 2.4.18
PHP 5.6.33
MySQL 5.7
phpinfo -> Server API FPM/FastCGI (thank to Juanga)

With FPM/FastCGI the times are the same as before.

I hope somebody has an idea where the problem could come from.

Yves

EDIT: @Juanga

Apache log:

```
[Tue Feb 20 20:51:24.097192 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 31539] AH01909: gs3-server.home:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Feb 20 20:51:24.120307 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 31540] AH01909: gs3-server.home:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Feb 20 20:51:24.122216 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31540] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 20 20:51:24.122232 2018] [core:notice] [pid 31540] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Feb 20 20:54:24.650985 2018] [:error] [pid 31545] [client 178.198.93.202:49568] PHP Warning:  include(page_content/con_car_search.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/start.php on line 34
[Tue Feb 20 20:54:24.651017 2018] [:error] [pid 31545] [client 178.198.93.202:49568] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'page_content/con_car_search.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/start.php on line 34
```

I found this before I cleaned the log file:

```
[Tue Feb 20 19:47:22.938070 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12711] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: Do you have anything on your apache logs? What's the SAPI for PHP (found at phpinfo), and again, something at those logs?

Comment: Wall of text, but the description of your problem is actually just this short sentence "I added an index but no changes.". Perhaps move that line to the top of your question, explain it better, and then add all the other info below, or discard.

Comment: Adding the index might have nothing to do with the slowness. I'm having a similar problem. I used to be able to retrieve 60000 rows within 1-2 minutes; now it is taking so long it seems like an infinite loop. I'm thinking that it could be the method Apache is configured to use PHP: maybe one method is slow and other is fast?